# Python raises exception "SystemExit: 1" on "sys.exit ( 1 )"

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder, image-registration, simpleitk

I am running the python example of simpleitk from this link 
https://simpleitk.readthedocs.io/en/master/Examples/ImageRegistrationMethod1/Documentation.html

in spyder anaconda.

I have installed packages simpleitk,system,os through anaconda Prompt .

```
from __future__ import print_function

import SimpleITK as sitk
import sys
import os


def command_iteration(method) :
    print("{0:3} = {1:10.5f} : {2}".format(method.GetOptimizerIteration(),
                                   method.GetMetricValue(),
                                   method.GetOptimizerPosition()))

if len ( sys.argv ) < 4:
    print( "Usage: {0} <fixedImageFilter> <movingImageFile> <outputTransformFile>".format(sys.argv[0]))
cc


fixed = sitk.ReadImage(sys.argv[1], sitk.sitkFloat32)
print(sys.argv[1])
moving = sitk.ReadImage(sys.argv[2], sitk.sitkFloat32)

R = sitk.ImageRegistrationMethod()
R.SetMetricAsMeanSquares()
R.SetOptimizerAsRegularStepGradientDescent(4.0, .01, 200 )
R.SetInitialTransform(sitk.TranslationTransform(fixed.GetDimension()))
R.SetInterpolator(sitk.sitkLinear)

R.AddCommand( sitk.sitkIterationEvent, lambda: command_iteration(R) )

outTx = R.Execute(fixed, moving)

print("-------")
print(outTx)
print("Optimizer stop condition: {0}".format(R.GetOptimizerStopConditionDescription()))
print(" Iteration: {0}".format(R.GetOptimizerIteration()))
print(" Metric value: {0}".format(R.GetMetricValue()))

sitk.WriteTransform(outTx,  sys.argv[3])

if ( not "SITK_NOSHOW" in os.environ ):

    resampler = sitk.ResampleImageFilter()
    resampler.SetReferenceImage(fixed);
    resampler.SetInterpolator(sitk.sitkLinear)
    resampler.SetDefaultPixelValue(100)
    resampler.SetTransform(outTx)

    out = resampler.Execute(moving)
    simg1 = sitk.Cast(sitk.RescaleIntensity(fixed), sitk.sitkUInt8)
    simg2 = sitk.Cast(sitk.RescaleIntensity(out), sitk.sitkUInt8)
    cimg = sitk.Compose(simg1, simg2, simg1//2.+simg2//2.)
    sitk.Show( cimg, "ImageRegistration1 Composition" )
```

On running this code it is giving me error following error 
Usage: E:/registration/simpleitk.py   
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

> SystemExit: 1
>
> C:\Users\aBC\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:3275:
>   UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.   warn("To exit:
>   use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)

How i can correct this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the script is not able to load an image in the call to sitk.ReadImage.  It is expecting a file name to be provided in the sys.argv[1] variable.  The script is designed to be run on the command line with the fixed image file name, the moving image file name and the output transform file name provided as command line arguments.

If you can't provide command line argument in Spyder (I don't know; I'm not familiar with it), you could hard code the file names in the script.

If you have further questions about SimpleITK, I suggest checking the ITK Discourse, discourse.itk.org.

Comment: I'm not familiar with command line argument in Spyder .How i can hard code the image names in the script------fixed = sitk.ReadImage(sys.argv[1], sitk.sitkFloat32)
moving = sitk.ReadImage(sys.argv[2], sitk.sitkFloat32)

Comment: Replace the sys.argv[2] argument with a string containing the file name.

Comment: I have made following changes in the code.....I replaced this... fixed = sitk.ReadImage(sys.argv[1], sitk.sitkFloat32) ...with this...
fixed = sitk.ReadImage("Picture1.png", sitk.sitkFloat32)...I replaced  this ...moving = sitk.ReadImage(sys.argv[2], sitk.sitkFloat32)... with.... moving = sitk.ReadImage("Picture2.png", sitk.sitkFloat32)
and this... sitk.WriteTransform(outTx,  sys.argv[3]) ...with this
sitk.WriteTransform(outTx, "output.png")..but it is show error at this line ...sitk.WriteTransform(outTx, "output.png")..

Comment: Error is :sitk.WriteTransform(outTx, "output.png")
 File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\SimpleITK\SimpleITK.py", 
    return _SimpleITK.WriteTransform(transform, filename)
RuntimeError: Exception thrown in SimpleITK WriteTransform: 
itk::ERROR:   Tried to create one of the following:
    HDF5TransformIOTemplate
    HDF5TransformIOTemplate
    MatlabTransformIOTemplate
    MatlabTransformIOTemplate
    TxtTransformIOTemplate
    TxtTransformIOTemplate
  You probably failed to set a file suffix, or
    set the suffix to an unsupported type.

Comment: PNG is not a Transform file format.  It is for images.  To write a transform file, you need to use a suffix of one of the supported formats.   The suffixes include '.txt', '.tfm', '.mat', and '.xfm'.

Comment: Now on sitting-- sitk.WriteTransform(outTx, "output.txt")-- it is showing following error .
  File "E:/registration/simpleitk.py", line 58, in <module>
    sitk.Show( cimg, "ImageRegistration1 Composition" )

  File "C:\Users\w\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\SimpleITK\SimpleITK.py", line 7887, in Show
    return _SimpleITK.Show(*args, **kwargs)

RuntimeError: Exception thrown in SimpleITK Show: C:\Users\dashboard\Miniconda3\conda-bld\simpleitk_1545325552986\work\Code\IO\src\sitkShow.cxx:495:
sitk::ERROR: No appropriate executable found.

Comment: The script does not produce a new image.  Registration simple produces a transform that goes from the moving image's space to the fixed image's space.  You would then need to use the transform to resample the moving image to the fixed image's space.

Comment: how to get rid of above error on  this line ...sitk.Show( cimg, "ImageRegistration1 Composition" )..

Comment: You need to install Fiji.  When the Show function is called, SimpleITK tries to display the image using the Fiji application.  You can download it from Fiji.sc.

Comment: i have installed fiji in anaconda prompt using this command....conda install -c hanslovsky fiji ......but this line ....sitk.Show( cimg, "ImageRegistration1 Composition" ) ...is still giving same error .....return _SimpleITK.Show(*args, **kwargs)

RuntimeError: Exception thrown in SimpleITK Show: C:\Users\dashboard\Miniconda3\conda-bld\simpleitk_1545325552986\work\Code\IO\src\sitkShow.cxx:495:
sitk::ERROR: No appropriate executable found.

Comment: SimpleITK expects Fiji to be found in the Program Files directory, your home directory or the Desktop.  I think Anaconda installs it somewhere else.It's probably easier for you to comment out the Show line and just write the image out as a file.  site.WriteImage(cimg, 'MyRegisteredImage.png'). Then you can use whatever image viewing application you like to open the PNG file.

Comment: After writing this line.... sitk.WriteImage(cimg, 'MyRegisteredImage.png')....no image named MyRegisteredImage.png appeared in project directory .How to get the the Registered Image?

Comment: It must have been written somewhere else.  If you give it a complete pathname, you can tell it exactly what directory to write the image to.